# Vim 8.0 Python support

Tags: vimscript-python, installing, linux-ubuntu

I'm trying to upgrade my Vim installation to version 8.0, but it doesn't support both Python and Python 3 as the below image.

(PS: Because of this problem, I cannot use the YCM (YouCompleteMe) plugin  now.)

1. I installed Vim 8.0 as in the following commands.
2. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus).

How can I handle this problem?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/vim
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vim
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like that version of Vim was compiled without Python support. Not a whole lot you can do about that. If you want to run the latest Vim version on Ubuntu then compiling it yourself is probably the easiest option.

Comment: No python, no ruby, no perl, no clipboard… that build is very close to useless. What do you get if you install `vim-gtk` instead of `vim`?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker How can I compile it by myself? Can you explain a little bit specific or giving me a link?

Comment: @romainl Is there vim-gtk which supports vim 8.0?

Comment: Yes, in that ppa.

Comment: not applicable if python and python3 are missing, but on debian stable (-python +python3) i found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/fasiha/8af2a4f719812319934947124bb63afd) works

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [pi-rho/dev PPA](https://launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+archive/ubuntu/dev) now supports Vim 8, and like it always has, includes support for Python/Python3:

```
$ vim --version | grep python
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3/dyn     +wildignore
$ apt-cache policy vim   
vim:
  Installed: 2:8.0.0134-1ubuntu1~ppa1~x
  Candidate: 2:8.0.0134-1ubuntu1~ppa1~x
  Version table:
 *** 2:8.0.0134-1ubuntu1~ppa1~x 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2 500
```

Of late, the `pi-rho/dev` PPA hasn't had updated Vim builds. I use the [`jonathonf/backports`](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/backports) PPA now:

```
$ vim --version | grep python
+comments          +libcall           -python            +vreplace
+conceal           +linebreak         +python3           +wildignore
$ apt-cache policy vim-gnome
vim-gnome:
  Installed: 2:8.0.1542-0york1~16.04
  Candidate: 2:8.0.1542-0york1~16.04
  Version table:
 *** 2:8.0.1542-0york1~16.04 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2 500
        500 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

The PPA also contains newer versions of several other packages.

Comment: ♦ Thanks, I used vim-nox alternatively. I should try this one.

Comment: how to install vim8 ? i added the PPA but executing `sudo apt-get install vim` gets me vim7 without pythin

Comment: @weima did you do an `apt-get update` after adding the PPA?

Comment: jonathonf/backports no longer has vim builds

Comment: @PengheGeng they moved it to [a separate PPA (`jonathonf/vim`)](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/vim)

Comment: @muru Yes, [jonathonf/vim](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/vim) works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

From your question it appears that you have installed vim-tiny 8.0 that is a very minimal Vim runtime without plugins. You can confirm this using this:

```
dpkg -l | grep vim
```

You can have several Vim runtimes, but the version running when you do `vim` will be the version that you can see indicated here:

```
update-alternatives --list vim
```

You can check other versions. My suggestion is that you decide between full versions with support for GUI, and you can choose between `vim-gtk2/vim-gtk3` packages or `vim-nox` that is a full version, but without a GUI.

Now, IIRC, the Vim full version in Debian/Ubuntu doesn't come with Python 2 AND Python 3 at the same time in 7.x versions. I don't know how the case is with Vim 8, because I use `neovim` now. If this is the case for you and you are going to need BOTH Python engines supported by Vim 8 (this will not be your case for use `YouCompleteMe`; this one works with Python 2 support only) then you will need to compile from sources your own Vim 8.0.

Comment: Soils Thanks, I installed vim-nox, however I would try to compile from sources someday.

Answer (score 6):

you should use

`sudo apt-get install vim-nox`

instead, to get a "huge-version".

Comment: I want to use vim 8.0 or later. Is there vim.nox which supports that?

Comment: @HyunHoYeo looks like vim-nox in Ubuntu 16.04 is vim 8.0 (you can check after install by doing `vim --version` and I got `VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Feb 05 2017 20:17:49)`

Comment: @jamescampbell Thanks, I upgraded my Ubuntu to 16.04 version and downloaded it.

Comment: This works on Debian 11.

Answer (score 6):

## Solution 1 :

- Install VIM Editor(Install any one of them of vim variant) :

  - **vim-gtk3** :-  This package contains a version of vim compiled with a GTK3 GUI and support for scripting with Lua, Perl, Python, Ruby, and Tcl. In order to install this package :

    ```
    sudo apt install vim-gtk3
    ```
  - **vim-gtk** :- This package contains a version of vim compiled with a GTK2 GUI and support for scripting with Lua, Perl, Python, Ruby, and Tcl. In order to install this package :

    ```
    sudo apt install vim-gtk
    ```
  - **vim-nox** :- enhanced vi editor
    Like vim-tiny, vim-nox is a minimal vim installation and support for
    scripting with Lua, Perl, Python, Ruby, and Tcl but no GUI. It comes with mouse support, but no clipboard support, IIRC. In order to install this package :

    ```
    sudo apt install vim-nox
    ```
- Set Vim as a default editor(assuming installed variant is **vim-gtk3**)

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/bin/vim.gtk3 1   
  sudo update-alternatives --set editor /usr/bin/vim.gtk3   
  sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/vi vi /usr/bin/vim.gtk3 1  
  sudo update-alternatives --set vi /usr/bin/vim.gtk3   
  sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/vi vim /usr/bin/vim.gtk3 1  
  sudo update-alternatives --set vim /usr/bin/vim.gtk3
  ```

## Solution 2 :

Otherwise, you can compile Vim from source code (assuming you're using Debian based system)

## Prepare your system

- Install

  ```
  sudo apt install libncurses5-dev \
  libgtk2.0-dev libatk1.0-dev \
  libcairo2-dev python-dev \
  python3-dev git
  ```
- Remove Vim if you already have

  ```
  sudo apt remove vim vim-runtime gvim
  ```

## configure and make

```
cd /usr && sudo git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git && cd vim  

sudo ./configure --with-features=huge \
--enable-multibyte \
--enable-pythoninterp=yes \
--with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/ \  # pay attention here check directory correct
--enable-python3interp=yes \
--with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu/ \  # pay attention here check directory correct
--enable-gui=gtk2 \
--enable-cscope \ 
--prefix=/usr/local/

sudo make VIMRUNTIMEDIR=/usr/local/share/vim/vim81
```

## Preparing deb package using [checkinstall](https://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall)

- And install that package

  ```
  cd /usr/vim && sudo checkinstall
  ```
- Or, if want to just create a package use `--install=no` option with checkinstall

## Set Vim as a default editor

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/local/bin/vim 1
sudo update-alternatives --set editor /usr/local/bin/vim
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/vi vi /usr/local/bin/vim 1
sudo update-alternatives --set vi /usr/local/bin/vim
```

## Verify that you're running the new Vim binary by looking

```
vim --version | grep python
```

**References :**
  - [Building Vim from Source](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source)
  - [checkinstall](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/checkinstall/checkinstall.8.en.html)
- [VIM variants](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281886/what-are-the-differences-between-the-different-vim-packages-available-in-ubuntu)

Comment: +1 for `sudo apt install vim-nox`

Answer (score 5):

You should install vim from source. That way, you have control over what is included. See the following for more info and a step by step walkthrough. It is relatively easy.

```
https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source
https://github.com/vim/vim
```

Comment: Please avoid posting a link-only answer since it could change in the future, leaving people with no answer to their question.  At least include the essential parts from the linked page.

Answer (score 1):

Just checked, the vim-nox (v. 8.1) available from the PPA had been compiled with Python 3 (only, not both, if you *really* need both I would advise to switch to Neovim).

Answer (score 0):

This is only for Windows guys who got the similar issure:

On Windows 64-bit, you MUST install the same bit python version as your VIM. 
etc.

```
32bit vim => 32bit python
64bit vim => 64bit python
```

Otherwise python2x.dll or python3x.dll will NOT be loaded.

Comment: OP was using a vim binary that was compiled without Python. Additionally, he's using it on Linux, not Windows.

Comment: @HerbWolfe yes, I know. It may not be proper but I put it here just for some windows guys who hit this post for solution. I spent hours to resolve this issue and want to same others some time on it. But thank you for the reminding.