# How to enable +python feature in vim

Tags: installing

I want to install a vim plugin, this plugin needs a `+python` feature, so when I open vim and type `:version` it displays `-python`. How can I make it enable?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to compile Vim yourself or get a prebuilt Vim package that was compiled with Python support.

If you're on a Debian based system, the easiest way is to download the vim-gnome or vim-gtk package from `apt` (`apt install vim-gtk` for instance). Other distros might have a similar package with python support built in.

If you'd prefer to compile Vim yourself, download the Vim repository and pass in `--enable-pythoninterp` like so:

```
cd /tmp && git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git && cd vim
./configure --enable-pythoninterp --prefix=/usr
make && sudo make install
```

On Windows, you can get the Gvim package from [here](https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/releases/tag/v8.0.0003) which includes Python support.

Comment: Thanks. I also found this, http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10242/vim-8-0-python-support

Comment: For your own compiled packages, it should be installed under /usr/local not /usr. That may mess up package manager installed stuff. The best way to install dependencies is something like `apt build-dep vim-nox`

Comment: It seems that, these days, vim-gtk installs Python 3 (as one would hope!). I was confused when `:echo has('python')` was still returning `0`, until I realised `:echo has('python3')` returned `1`. Hopefully the plugin I want to use will be happy with that. (I'm running Mint 19 Cinnamon, FWIW.)

Answer (score 11):

## Solution 1 :

- Install `vim-gtk` package

  ```
  sudo apt install vim-gtk
  ```
- Set Vim as a default editor

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/bin/vim.gtk 1   
  sudo update-alternatives --set editor /usr/bin/vim.gtk   
  sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/vi vi /usr/bin/vim.gtk 1  
  sudo update-alternatives --set vi /usr/bin/vim.gtk   
  sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/vi vim /usr/bin/vim.gtk 1  
  sudo update-alternatives --set vim /usr/bin/vim.gtk
  ```

## Solution 2 :

Otherwise you need to compile Vim from source code(assuming you're using Debian based system)

## Prepare your system

- Install

  ```
  sudo apt install libncurses5-dev \
  libgtk2.0-dev libatk1.0-dev \
  libcairo2-dev python-dev \
  python3-dev git
  ```
- Remove Vim if you already have

  ```
  sudo apt remove vim vim-runtime gvim
  ```

## configure and make

```
cd /usr && sudo git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git && cd vim  

sudo ./configure --with-features=huge \
--enable-multibyte \
--enable-pythoninterp=yes \
--with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/ \  # pay attention here check directory correct
--enable-python3interp=yes \
--with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu/ \  # pay attention here check directory correct
--enable-gui=gtk2 \
--enable-cscope \ 
--prefix=/usr/local/

sudo make VIMRUNTIMEDIR=/usr/local/share/vim/vim81
```

## Preparing deb package using [checkinstall](https://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall)

- And install that package

  ```
  cd /usr/vim && sudo checkinstall
  ```
- Or, if want to just create a package use `--install=no` option with checkinstall

## Set Vim as a default editor

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/local/bin/vim 1
sudo update-alternatives --set editor /usr/local/bin/vim
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/vi vi /usr/local/bin/vim 1
sudo update-alternatives --set vi /usr/local/bin/vim
```

## Verify that you're running the new Vim binary by looking

```
vim --version | grep python
```

**Reference :**
  - [Building Vim from Source](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source)
  - [checkinstall](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/checkinstall/checkinstall.8.en.html)

Comment: Instead of linking to some deb on a random Internet site, you should rather recommend to install the official Vim from the Debian package that has `+python` available. I believe this should be `vim-gtk`

Comment: Thanks @ChristianBrabandt for comment, I will update my answer.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I believe the python option for the current Debian packages `vim-gtk3` and `vim-gtk` is no longer by default included.

Comment: @jacob you mean current debian does not include `+python` anymore? Could it be debian switched to python3?

Answer (score 7):

In order to support python-mode you need to have +python AND +python3. This should get you there (at least on macOS):

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/local --with-features=huge --enable-pythoninterp --enable-python3interp

make

sudo make install
```

Answer (score 6):

For Windows you can always grab the very latest patched version of Vim 8.x compiled against the latest external libraries here: [Vim downloads](https://tuxproject.de/projects/vim/x64/)

At the time of posting the most current versions:

Latest compiled update: 2017-02-23

Vim version: 8.0.0363 [Official patch log](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/8.0/README)

Libraries used: Perl 5.24.1, Python 2.7.12, Python 3.6.0, Racket 6.7, Ruby 2.4.0, Lua 5.3.3, Tcl 8.6.4, and libXpm

Answer (score 5):

For a server instalation without GUI use `vim-nox` instead.

`apt install vim-nox`

Answer (score 4):

You need to install a Python version on your system with the same bitness (either 32-bit or 64-bit) as your vim. Python needs to be in your PATH. If you can run it by typing `python` on a command prompt you should be good in this regard. Finally vim needs to be compiled to support python, but in my experience most are. Check with `:version` and look for `python/dyn`. It needs to have a plus in front of it.

Answer (score 4):

Since this could be misinterpreted with enable the python3 feature, I consider useful mention this link for an installation according to your needs

**Here are excellent guides for: [*nix & windows](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki).**

*Note*: Pay attention to every character in the ./configure instruction and read carefully (as if you'll screw up) before doing it. And read until the end, there is no way to get lost

You should probably add this to ./configure:

```
--enable-fail-if-missing
```

Avoid to enable both python 2 & 3

**Take your time** This is a very very well explained procedure. Thank to Valloric

Answer (score 3):

If, like me, despite having compiled `vim` with `python3` support, you get an error that `python3` support is missing, make sure it loads the correct `dll`.

#### Check feature exists

```
:version
```

```
...
+python3/dyn
...
```

#### Python3 is missing during runtime

```
:echo has('python3')
```

```
0
```

#### Incorrect DDL used

```
:verbose set pythondll?
```

```
libpython2.7.so.1.0
```

[This comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/7fyvgz/easiest_way_to_have_vim_with_python3_support_from/dqfh9gt?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) deserves the credit for suggesting this option.

#### Solution

Adding `set pythondll=libpython3.8.so` to .vimrc solved the issue by telling vim to use that `dll` when it needs `python3`. Vim's `:help python-dynamic` explains it

```
The 'pythondll' or 'pythonthreedll' option can be used to specify the Python       
shared library file instead of DYNAMIC_PYTHON_DLL or DYNAMIC_PYTHON3_DLL file      
what were specified at compile time.  The version of the shared library must       
match the Python 2.x or Python 3 version Vim was compiled with.
```

I couldn't find an explicit way to query what value `DYNAMIC_PYTHON3_DLL` was at compile time. At the time of this writing, I assumed it's the system's version.

#### What is python3-dynamic (python3/dyn)

For those curious, this is included in `:help python-dynamic`, too.

```
On MS-Windows and Unix the Python library can be loaded dynamically.  The :version output then includes +python/dyn or +python3/dyn.                      

This means that Vim will search for the Python DLL or shared library file only  
when needed.  When you don't use the Python interface you don't need it, thus   
you can use Vim without this file.
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS X, you can use `homebrew` to install first python and then vim, which vim will support python.

I use MBP, the vim support `python/dyn` installed by the above way, but not including `python3`.

---

# Delete wrong ans 2017.2.28 10:38AM #

Comment: I am not sure if I read that correctly or not, but note that in the help page, you can never see, if your Vim actually supports `+python` or `-python`. You have to look into `:version`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt you are right.  Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

For those using anaconda python, some additional modifications are requited. They might want to compile vim as well, especially if you want code-completion. Here is the configure command:

### Modified configure command for anaconda:

```
 ./configure --enable-terminal --enable-gui=auto \
      --with-features=huge \
      --enable-multibyte \
       --enable-cscope --enable-terminal --enable-gui=auto  \
      --prefix=/XXX/SOFTWARE/VIM8/install3 \
   --enable-python3interp \
   --with-python3-config-dir=/XXX/anaconda2/envs/py36/bin/python3.6-config \
   --includedir=/XXX/anaconda2/envs/py36/include  \
   --includedir=/XXX/anaconda2/envs/py36/include/python3.6m \
   LDFLAGS=" -L/XXX/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib -L/XXX/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu"
```

Here, vim is being installed to `/XXX/SOFTWARE/VIM8/install3` using anaconda environment for python 3.6 installed in `/XXX/anaconda2/envs/py36`