# Installing clang_complete Errors

Tags: vimrc, filetype-c++, plugin-clang-complete

I tried to add the clang_complete plugin to my vim.
https://github.com/xavierd/clang_complete

After I added it, I get a large error page before I can open any C++ file. The autocomplete still does not work. I looked through some old threads and wondered if it could be because I don't have a +python3 on my :version page.  I followed the steps [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11526/how-to-enable-python-feature-in-vim#:~:text=You%20need%20to%20compile%20Vim,with%20python%20support%20built%20in.) to try to activate python3, but I still have a -python3.

Is this error because of that?

I use a Mac.

Error message looks like this. [image]

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This *could* be a python3 error; it’s possible the memory error or name error would be resolved using python 2 instead of python 3. But you’ll probably have better luck discussing with plugin maintainers. Also, for the future, [please don’t post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Comment: Which suggestions did you try to get Vim with `+python3`? Are you using Homebrew? On the Mac it's probably the easiest way to get it working... Make sure you're running the Homebrew binary and not the system one.

Comment: Also, you cant try `coc` plugin, which is much easier to setup.