# Can't have a proper version of vim with Python

Tags: vimrc, functions

I am on Mint 18.3 Sylvia. I tried to install different versions of vim to have python support, following diverse advices (vim/vim.bacic/vim.gnome/vim.gtk/vim.gtk3/vim compiled from git). I have now the choice between 6 alternatives. None of them happen to have python support. Some of them have python3, which seems totally useless to me:

```
vi --version | grep "python"
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3         +wildignore
```

When I try to install my plugins with Vumble I have the following error:

```
Error: Required vim compiled with +python
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vim 8.0 Python support](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10242/vim-8-0-python-support)

Comment: No, I already tried to install all of these vim versions. I always end up with a problem to use YouCompleteMe
In my vim version, I can either have : +python/dyn or +python3, but I always end up with an error when I try to use Plugins that need python support in my .vimrc (YouCompleteMe unavailable: unable to load Python. / Error: Required vim compiled with +python)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you explain exactly what you tried? I'm having trouble following "diverse advices (list of vims)"—if none of them have python support, none of them have python support. However, generally when compiling yourself, *you* choose the available features. So, is your question (maybe) "how can I compile vim with `+python`?"

Comment: Thank you! I downloaded several versions of vim that were supposed to have python support, none of them had python support (`-python`), some of them had the `+python3`. Firstable, I don't see why my vim Plugins could not use python3. python is just a generic command, and anyway I only use 3.X python. And secondly yes, I would be interested to know how I can compile my own vim version with python support.

Comment: @ant.kr: Please refer to the already linked question where [Section 2](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/17559/246) of this answer might help you out. It describes how to compile vim with both python2 and python3 support, if you need it. The reason why some plugins depend on python2 could be simply because they don't support python3 yet. Try contacting the developer of the plugin to see if they could update their plugin to link with python3 instead.